# how do I append a cdn url to image tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, cdn

I am working asp.net mvc application. I am outputting some html on to a view which is supplied via another application. I want to be able to take this html and append a CDN domain to all image tags. I am not sure how to do this but would like some suggestions.

Comment: just modify it before output or on client side by changing SRC attribute of the images? what seem to be the problem?

Comment: need more detail than that

Comment: Exactly. Provide the minimum code that does the output, the structure of HTML/existing image tags and what you want them to look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be to use the Html Agility Pack [[link](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com)] in your controller.

For example:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
...
private string AppendCdnToImgSrc(string htmlString)
{
    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlString); // or htmlDoc.Load(htmlFileName) if a file

    foreach(HtmlNode img in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//img[@src]")
    {
        HtmlAttribute attribute = img["src"];
        attribute.Value = attribute.Value + ".cdn";
    }

    // return string output...
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    htmlDoc.Save(memStream)
    memStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memStream);
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```